# Running OUnit tests using dune

Tags: ocaml, ounit, ocaml-dune

I'm having difficulties running OUnit tests, mostly because I'm new to both dune and OUnit. `dune` complains when I run `dune runtest`:

```
File "test/dune", line 4, characters 13-14:
Error: Library "f" not found.
Hint: try: dune external-lib-deps --missing @runtest
```

Here's the project structure:

```
├── dune
├── f.ml  # This is the source file.
└── test
    ├── dune
    └── f_test.ml  # This is the test.
```

This is `dune`:

```lisp
(executable
  (name f))
```

This is `test/dune`:

```lisp
(test
  (name f_test)
  (libraries oUnit f))  ; <- `f` here causes problems.
```

I can see that the error appears because dune does not know about `f.ml`, and hence does not know about `f` in the dune file.

How can I make dune compile `f.ml` in such a way that `test/dune` knows about the `f` library that I use in `test/f_test.ml`? How can I run the unit tests properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is to split `f` into a private library and an executable, and then test the split library.

EDIT:

For instance, the project structure could be updated to

```
├── dune
├── f.ml  # f only contains the I/O glue code.
├── lib
|    ├── dune
|    └── a.ml  # a implements the features that need to be tested.
└── test
    ├── dune
    └── test.ml  # This is the test.
```

with `dune`

```lisp
 (executable (name main) (libraries Lib))
```

For the test, `test/dune`:

```lisp
(test (name test) (libraries Lib oUnit))
```

and finally `lib/dune`

```lisp
(library (name Lib))
```

With this setup, the test can be run with `dune runtest`.